# Abrir una imagen en la galeria conociendo su ruta en Flutter

Tags: flutter

Estoy trabajando con imágenes en un proyecto, hasta ahora he abierto las imágenes y las he mostrado dentro de la aplicación, pero ahora necesito hacer algo diferente.

Tengo la ruta de esas imágenes guardadas y lo que necesito es, que al hacerle tap a cierto Widget que tiene guardada esa ruta, me abra la imagen en la galeria. He buscado cosillas pero  no encuentro nada al respecto. ¿ Es esto posible?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con abrirlo en la galería? Te refieres a que cuando en tu app se le haga click a un widget, la "app galería" de tu móvil se abra y muestre una imagen en concreto?

De ser así, lo veo complicado, ya que eso se podría manejar, creo desde nativo. Además, no podrás conseguir que se abra directamente, sino que te salga una lista de apps, que puede abrir el archivo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puede usar el paquete [open_file](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file) para abrir una imagen en la Galería. Agregue open_file como una dependencia en su archivo pubspec.yaml. Luego usa esto código para abrir la imagen en la galería:

```
import 'package:open_file/open_file.dart';

OpenFile.open('ruta a imagen');
```

Comment: Efectivamente así me ha funcionado. Era más sencillo de lo que parecía, muchas gracias.

Comment: Mi placer. La mayor parte de lo que encontré fue sobre el uso del paquete image_picker, pero eso no era lo que estabas buscando. La recompensa me motivó a encontrar la respuesta. XD